# Intellij says my golang Package import contains test files only and asks me to delete import

Tags: intellij-idea

IntelliJ reports an error on my import stating that package contains test files only and asks me to delete the import.

It also doesn't recognize the object.

However, the package contains [more than test files](https://github.com/containernetworking/plugins/blob/main/pkg/ns/ns_linux.go), and it is being utilized by my projects.

How do I fix this IntelliJ Behavior?

[image]

Comment: I think you're working on macOS and this package has `_linux.go` namespace. Please try to edit OS in settings to `linux` to see if it helps (_Preferences | Go | Build Tags & Vendoring_).

Comment: Yes, that was it. Thank you. Could you write this as an answer so that I can accept that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`containernetworking/plugins/pkg/ns` directory has `_linux.go` namespaces so you should configure the corresponding OS if that differs from your main one in GoLand settings: *Preferences | Go | Build Tags & Vendoring* (set *OS* to *Linux*).

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem, but no operating system namesake was involved. For reasons unknown, Goland decided to classify a file named transaction.go as a text file. Renaming the file to transaction2.go worked around the issue, but I wanted to keep the filename. Finally, I went into the file associations on the file menu and forced th association to Go. That resolved. I don't understand why that was necessary.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34270144)